# DeepSpeech Installation Error: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, dll, pip, virtualenv, mozilla-deepspeech

I am attempting to build a speech-to-text algorithm using Mozilla DeepSpeech, but I am having trouble installing the package.

First, I created a new virtual environment in Anaconda called `deepspeech-venv` and installed the latest version of the `deepspeech` package (v0.8.1) via `pip` in the Anaconda Powershell with the command `pip install deepspeech --upgrade`.

Next, I downloaded both the `pbmm` version and the `tflite` version of the pre-trained English models from Mozilla's GitHub using the commands `wget https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.8.1/deepspeech-0.8.1-models.pbmm` and `wget https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.8.1/deepspeech-0.8.1-models.tflite`.

Finally, I wanted to check and make sure that everything installed correctly, so I typed `deepspeech -h` into the command line, which produced the following error statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\zachary.holden\anaconda3\envs\deepspeech_venv\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\zachary.holden\anaconda3\envs\deepspeech_venv\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\zachary.holden\Anaconda3\envs\deepspeech_venv\Scripts\deepspeech.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zachary.holden\anaconda3\envs\deepspeech_venv\lib\site-packages\deepspeech\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from deepspeech.impl import Version as version
  File "c:\users\zachary.holden\anaconda3\envs\deepspeech_venv\lib\site-packages\deepspeech\impl.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _impl
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

From what I understand, this means that I'm lacking some dependencies for the `deepspeech` library; however, I'm not quite sure what additional DLLs need to be installed or even how to go about that process. (Unless, of course, if the issue lies in my installation process, and I merely have to add another library.)

NOTE: I am running Python v3.7.7 on a Windows 10 64-bit system.

Answer (score 2):

I copied the "libdeepspeech.so" file from "lib" directory to directly under "deepspeech" directory as suggested in the below shared link and it worked for me.

[Reference Link](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-when-running-deepspeech/63832/3)

Comment: I was able to solve the ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _impl: The specified module could not be found. issue by following the suggestion above i.e., by moving libdeepspeech.so from Lib/site-packages/deepspeech/lib/libdeepspeech.so to Lib/site-packages/deepspeech/libdeepspeech.so.